# Закрывается модал только при клике фон

Tags: javascript

Как сделать чтобы закрывается модал только при клике фон (`.modal`)? А при клике контент(`#modal`) не закрывается. Посмотрите через "На всю страницу" :)

```js
$('body').on('click', '#open', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $(".modal").show();
});
$('body').on('click', '.modal', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".modal").hide();
});
```

```css
.modal {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    position: fixed;
    padding: 50px 0;
    z-index: 1000;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: none;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: overlay;
}
#modal {
    width: 700px;
    margin: auto;
    background: #FFF;
    box-shadow: 0 10px 40px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
#modal_content {
    width: 700px;
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="open">Open modal</a>
<div class="modal">
    <div id="modal">
        <div id="modal_content">
            Modal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal content
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('body').on('click', '#open', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $(".modal").show();
});
$('body').on('click', '.modal', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".modal").hide();
});

//если что-то не должно реагировать на клик, то 
//надо просто сделать так:
$('.modal').children().click(function(e) {
  return false;
});
```

```css
.modal {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    position: fixed;
    padding: 50px 0;
    z-index: 1000;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: none;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: overlay;
}
#modal {
    width: 700px;
    margin: auto;
    background: #FFF;
    box-shadow: 0 10px 40px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
#modal_content {
    width: 700px;
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="open">Open modal</a>
<div class="modal">
    <div id="modal">
        <div id="modal_content">
            Modal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal contentModal content
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sergey Snegirev спасибо вам!